# Is it possible or necessary to set the content type of a ServiceStack client delete request?

Tags: c#, json, rest, servicestack

I have the following code.

```
public T SendUpdateRequest(string url)
{
    using (JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient())
    {
        T response = client.Put<T>(url);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I have similar methods for create and delete requests, calling the JsonServiceClient `Post` and `Delete` methods respectively.

When calling my update or create methods, the call to the external API works fine. Delete does not. I can see that the API's delete method does indeed work if I fire a request to it via [REST console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en).

When I compare my non-working delete with the working one's request/response in Fiddler, I can see the main difference is my request is not setting `content-type` to `application/json` (all these methods return JSON).

My question is, is it possible (or even necessary) to explicitly set the `content-type` of my delete request to `application/json` in order to successfully call my API method?

Comment: As a side note. Be careful about using a `new JsonServiceClient()` for each request, as the client is the container for cookies, and therefore if you receive a session cookie in one client it won't be available to the other instances. It's best to create one instance of the client and share it amongst the requests.

Comment: The `Content-Type` HTTP Header is used to identify what format the HTTP Request BODY is in. As HTTP `GET` and `DELETE` requests have no Request Body, no `Content-Type` is added as expected. You may instead be looking for the `Accept` header which indicates what format the client would like the response body in, which in ServiceStack's `JsonServiceClient` is always `application/json`.

Comment: Excellent advice all round, thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ServiceStack clients do not set the `content-type` header on requests where there is no request body, as the `content-type` only applies to the body, and is therefore redundant.

This [can be seen here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceClientBase.cs#L692) in the code that prepares the client request.

```cs
if (httpMethod.HasRequestBody())
{
    client.ContentType = ContentType;
    ...
```

A correctly implemented RESTful service should be happy with a `DELETE` request without `content-type` being specified where there is no body.

```
DELETE /User/123 HTTP/1.1
```

If the service you are calling is not happy with your request without this type being specified *(which is unusual)*, then you can manually enforce the sending of the type using this filter:

```cs
var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://service/");
client.RequestFilter += (httpReq) => {
    // Force content type to be sent on all requests
    httpReq.ContentType = "application/json";
};
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You're exactly right Scott. It appears the service I'm calling won't play ball when this isn't explicitly specified (which isn't surprising given other gotchas I've seen with it). Anyway your bottom code block did the trick - thank you.